# PyCharm, python framework builds, and Mac OSX

Tags: python, macos, matplotlib, pycharm

I have been fighting with PyCharm on my OSX machine for a while, trying to understand why it can't find some things in mpl_toolkits.  I have pretty well decided that the problem is that something went wrong with the matplotlib build in the default python interpreter that PyCharm uses.  This is a Mac "framework" build located in `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework`.

I have tried to solve this in two ways.  First, I made sure that I had another working python interpreter -- able to deal with mpl_toolkits with no problem -- and then pointed PyCharm to it instead of to the default interpreter.  When I do that, PyCharm can't even use matplotlib, let alone mpl_toolkits, because -- as it tells me -- I am not using a "framework build".  Second, I tried to monkey with the default build and re-build matlotlib within it.  Can't do it because the system won't let me touch it even if I am running under `sudo`.

So, I either need to

1. create my own "framework build" of python or
2. figure out how to get around the system prohibitions and re-install matplotlib in the existing "framework build".

I have looked around on the internet and can't find much on how to do **1**.  Can't find anything on how to do **2**, and it seems kind of dangerous anyway.

Does anyone know how to do either of these?
Anyone have another approach that might work?